# Loading spinner after PayPal payment

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, paypal

So I'm building a Django e-commerce which allows payments via PayPal. Once the user introduces all his PayPal information and presses pay, the PayPal window disappears and take a few seconds to call the function I put inside onApprove. As I show here:

```
    // Finalize the transaction
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
            submitFormData(); //redirects to the Thank you page
        });
    }
```

As I said it takes a few seconds (3 or 4) to execute the call submitFormData() after the customer accepted the transaction.
Is there any way I can put a loading spinner in the middle of the screen? I imagine I can but honestly I don't know where to start.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use busyLoad with font awesome for example: https://piccard21.github.io/busy-load/

```
$.busyLoadSetup({ fontawesome: "fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw" });
// Finalize the transaction
onApprove: function (data, actions) {
    return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
        $.busyLoadFull("show");
        submitFormData().promise().done(function() {
            $.busyLoadFull("hide");      
        });    
    });
}
```